# Creating project firstapp... Resolving dependencies in firstapp... (1:58.9s)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

When I run in terminal `flutter create firstapp` is stuck it's showing resolving dependencies.

`C:\dev>flutter create firstapp`

`Creating project firstapp...`

`Resolving dependencies in firstapp... (6:04.2s)`

This `Resolving dependencies` only shows up when creating a first app and it took about 2-3 hours and it is still building.

[Screenshot of Creating Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B9jl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by doing:

- Uninstall VS Code dart and flutter extensions and close VS Code.
- After this go to: vscode\extensions and remove all the files.
- Run VS Code As Administrator.
- Open VS Code and install dart and flutter extensions.

The cause for me might be that when you uninstall an extension files aren't erased.

I hope I helped you

Comment: it is still resolving dependencies showing in the terminal. Any alternative solutions? i waited like 30 minutes before i comment, i completely wipe my vscode\extensions and reinstall it and run as administrator.

Comment: i also reinstall my vscode so I can have a clean start but I'm still waiting for my firstapp to be created.